# C# InteropServices and Visual Basic 6.0 error reference error

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, vb6, vb

Yo realicé en C# un dll para usar con Visual Basic 6. 
Cuando creo la referencia en vb6 VB6 me da el siguiente error:

> Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Lo he intentado de varias formas pero me da el siempre el mismo error, ya lo registré
con REGASM solcomfe.dll /tlb:com.solcomfe.tlb, pero siempre es el mismo problema.
Compilo con Any Cpu en Visual Studio 2015, compilo con x86 y el problema es el mismo.

**VISUAL BASIC 6.0** Codigo:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

 Dim objhacienda As SolcomFE.clsHacienda
 Set objhacienda = New SOLCOMFE.clsHacienda' Error can not create the object 429
 Dim blnResult As Boolean
 blnResult = objhacienda.tengoAcceso Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set
end sub
```

**C#** Codigo:

```
namespace SolcomFE
{


[
    ComVisible(true), //Hace visible las interfaces
    GuidAttribute("4F52E06E-29C6-4168-8AC2-F836CD7A1C4A"),  //Tomado del asembly del proyecto
    Description("Interfaces para acceso de factura electronica")
    //      ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)

    ]

//----------------------------------------------------Diseño de interfaces -------------------------------------//
public interface IclsHacienda
{

    [DispId(1)]
    bool tengoAcceso();

    [DispId(2)]
    void configuracion(bool pBlnEnvioProduccion,
                 string pStrUsuarioHacienda,
                 string pStrClaveHacienda,
                string pStrPinCerti,
                string pStrRutaCerti,
           string pStrRutaArchEnvio = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/",
                 string pStrRutaArchRespuesta = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/");

    [DispId(3)]
    string[] registrarDocElectronico(
                string pStrVerificador,
                 byte pBytSituacionEnCom,
                DocumentoEncabezado pLstEncabezadoDoc
                );
}


//-------------------------------------------Clases ---------------------------------------------------------//

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("64B7C116-BA68-4EE0-8340-74F64846CB3D")]
public class clsHacienda : IclsHacienda
{
    //------------------------------------------ Atributos de la clase --------------------------------------//


    private bool EnvioProduccion //
    {
        get
        {
            return envioProduccion;
        }
        set
        {
            envioProduccion = value;
        }
    }

    private string UsuarioHacienda //
    {
        get
        {
            return usuariohacienda;
        }
        set
        {
            usuariohacienda = value;
        }
    }

    private string ClaveHacienda //
    {
        get
        {
            return clavehacienda;
        }
        set
        {
            clavehacienda = value;
        }
    }
    private string RutaCertificado
    {
        get
        {
            return rutacertificado;
        }
        set
        {
            rutacertificado = value;
        }
    }



    private string RutaArchEnvio
    {
        get
        {
            return rutaarchenvio;
        }
        set
        {
            rutaarchenvio = value;
        }
    }

    private string RutArchrespuesta
    {
        get
        {
            return rutaarchrespuesta;
        }
        set
        {
            rutaarchrespuesta = value;
        }
    }


    private string PinCertificado
    {
        get
        {
            return pincertificado;
        }
        set
        {
            pincertificado = value;
        }
    }




    public clsHacienda() { } 

    public bool tengoAcceso() { return true; }


    public void configuracion(bool pBlnEnvioProduccion,
                 string pStrUsuarioHacienda,
                 string pStrClaveHacienda,
                string pStrPinCerti,
                string pStrRutaCerti,
           string pStrRutaArchEnvio = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/",
                 string pStrRutaArchRespuesta = "C://HACIENDA/Almacenamiento/")

    {
        EnvioProduccion = pBlnEnvioProduccion;

        UsuarioHacienda = pStrUsuarioHacienda;
        ClaveHacienda = pStrClaveHacienda;
        PinCertificado = pStrPinCerti;
        RutaCertificado = pStrRutaCerti;
        RutaArchEnvio = pStrRutaArchEnvio;
        RutArchrespuesta = pStrRutaArchRespuesta;
    }

    public string[] registrarDocElectronico(
                string pStrVerificador,
                 byte pBytSituacionEnCom,
                DocumentoEncabezado pLstEncabezadoDoc
                 )
    {
        string[] strArrValores = new string[10];
        return strArrValores;
    }




  }

}
```

Comment: ¿Ejecutaste `regasm` como administrador? ¿Lo registró correctamente?

Comment: si ejecuté regasm como administrador y lo registró correctamente, el problema es cuando lo llama desde vb6.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución

Crear 2 clases, inteface ,la clase de los metodos
Ejemplo iInterface, COMInterface,
COMIterface implementa iInterface.

Ir a tools y create GUID
Cree una key. Implement_OleCreate and copielo en iInterface class,
despues cree una nueva la llave 5.Guid Class

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37338.com-interop-detail-steps-to-create-com-interop-dll.aspx

Comment: Me alegro de que hayas encontrado una solución y la hayas compartido con la comunidad. Pero me temo que la publicación, quizás debido al formato usado, no se entiende muy bien y puede no ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Te recomiendo que la edites siguiendo los consejos que encontrarás en [answer] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](/help/formatting). Un saludo.